# UCUM UnitFormat for JSR 363

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jsr363, ucum

I'm using JSR 363 "Units of Measurement" with the latest reference implementation:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.measure</groupId>
  <artifactId>unit-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>tec.units</groupId>
  <artifactId>unit-ri</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to print out "milliliters" in [UCUM](http://unitsofmeasure.org/ucum.html) format, i.e. "mL":

```
final UnitFormat unitFormat =
    ServiceProvider.current().getUnitFormatService().getUnitFormat();
final Unit<?> unit = MILLI(LITRE);
final String unitString=unitFormat.format(unit);
```

Unfortunately this gives me "ml", not "mL" from UCUM. And even though the JSR 363 specification (and source code) teases me throughout with references to the UCUM, `UnitFormatService.getAvailableFormatNames()` on the RI only gives me "ASCII" and "Default", so I can't use `getUnitFormat("UCUM")` as the JSR 363 specification hints that I should be able to do (if only someone would support UCUM).

So where can I get a JSR 363 `UnitFormat` implementation supporting the UCUM?

Comment: I tried to do a huge kludge by bringing in JScience 4.3.1 (which only supports JSR-275) just for formatting, but the source code for JScience `UnitFormat.getUCUMInstance()` seems to really return `UnitFormat.ASCII` with a comment: `TBD - Provide UCUM implementation.` Ugh.

Answer (score 2):

See the JSR 363 extension module https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-systems/tree/master/ucum-java8 for UCUM support.

It provides support for the Unified Code for Units of Measure on Java SE 8.
At the moment UCUM is more powerful and extensive, parsing uses a `SymbolMap` concept (based on Java ResourceBundles though it is not local-sensitive) so we cannot make it available for the JSR 363 RI. Please use the compatible Java SE 8 port [UoM SE](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/uom-se) if you can.

Answer (score 1):

In UCUM both **l** (lower case ell) and **L** are used for liter. The lower case is continental European style, the upper case is US style. Both are equivalent in UCUM. So it's just a style issue.